# Creating a mapping count

Tags: bash, shell

I have this data with two columns

```
Id Users
123 2
123 1
234 5
234 6
34 3
```

I want to create this count mapping from the given data like this

```
123 3
234 11
34 3
```

How can I do it in bash?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use associative arrays, something like

```
declare -A newmap
newmap["123"]=2
newmap["123"]=$(( ${newmap["123"]} + 1))
```

obviously you have to iterate through your input, see if the entry exists then add to it, else initialize it

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier with `awk`.

#### Solution 1: Doesn't expect the file to be sorted. Stores entire file in memory

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' file 
34 3
234 11
123 3
```

What we are doing here is using the first column as `key` and adding second column as value. In the `END` block we iterate over our array and print the `key=value` pair.

If you have the `Id Users` line in your input file and want to exclude it from the output, then add `NR>1` condition by saying:

```
awk 'NR>1{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' file
```

`NR>1` is telling `awk` to skip the first line. `NR` contains the line number so we instruct `awk` to start creating our array from second line onwards.

---

#### Solution 2: Expects the file to be sorted. Does not store the file in memory.

```
awk '$1!=prev && NR>1{print prev,sum}{prev=$1; sum+=$2}END{print prev,sum}' file
123 3
234 14
34 17
```

If you have the `Id Users` line in your input file and want to exclude it from the output, then add `NR>1` condition by saying:

```
awk '$1!=prev && NR>2{print prev, sum}NR>1{prev = $1; sum+=$2}END{print prev, sum}' ff
123 3
234 14
34 17
```

Answer (score 0):

A Bash (4.0+) solution:

```
declare -Ai count

while read a b ; do
  count[$a]+=b
done < "$infile"

for idx in ${!count[@]}; do
  echo  "${idx} ${count[$idx]}"
done
```

For a sorted output the last line should read

```
done | sort -n
```